# How do I get my asp.net onto Plesk (Parallels)?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, plesk

Take a look at this image here:

[image]

On the left is my Parallels Plesk Panel that I'm using through m6.net.  My asp.net project is in the folder on the right.  What folder should I upload all of these files into?  It includes a database, some images, and lots of aspx pages.  If there is a step I'm supposed to do in between, please tell me.  I can't find instructions on what I'm supposed to do anywhere.

---

**EDIT**

Ok, I found through Googling another site that told me to drag all the files on the right into the 'httpdocs' folder.  I've done that.  I now get an error because it can't access my sql databases (in the App_Data folder).  Is there a specific way I'm supposed to set up the databases so that they are accessible by Plesk?

Comment: u need to config the connection strings to match the database on your server , so check with your host or cpanel for database connection, u will find the connection stringin web.config file

Comment: @sari3x I'll go check it out, thanks.